# Oracle date column showing the wrong value

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I'm trying to identify a problem in a date colum in my table.
The database is Oracle 11g.

The situation is:
When I run the following query:

```
select to_char(data_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), a.data_val from material a order by a.data_val asc;
```

the five first lines of the result are:

```
00/00/0000  | 29/06/5585 00:00:00
00/00/0000  | 29/06/5585 00:00:00
00/00/0000  | 29/06/5585 00:00:00
11/11/1111  | 11/11/1111 00:00:00
01/01/1500  | 01/01/1500 00:00:00
```

the question is:

Why the to_char function of the first three lines returns a different value of date (00/00/0000)?

And why the date 29/06/5585 is the first result of a ASC date order by? It'll be right using: order by data_val DESC, will not?

Comment: The results are sorted correctly given the values to_char is returning. My guess is that the data_val column is not a Date data type. I'm not sure what the minimum and maximum dates that Oracle can cope with are, but I think 1500 is too early. Since data_val is not a date type, I'd expect the first 3 to give something sensible, and the last two appear to have been unchanged which is one outcome if Oracle doesn't recognise them as dates. Check the date range Oracle supports, and the formats to_char takes (is MM month or minutes?)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an Oracle limitation.  `SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '5585-06-29', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM Dual;` works fine.

Comment: The dava_val column is a date type. And according to oracle documention: Oracle Database can store dates in the Julian era, ranging from January 1, 4712 BCE through December 31, 9999 CE (Common Era, or 'AD')

Comment: Must be something we're not seeing.  Can you post a repro on SQLFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered the same problem. I can confirm that the "date" column is indeed the DATE type.
The date in question is 01-May-2014, so it's most likely not related to the big year number in the original post. And when you perform some calculation with the date, the problem is fixed, i.e. TO_CHAR(datum) would be all zeros, TO_CHAR(datum + 1) would be as expected, and even TO_CHAR(datum +1 -1) would be correct. (TO_CHAR(datum+0) doesn't help :))

Based on the DUMP value it seems that the problem is that we've somehow managed to store 31-Apr-2014 rather than 01-May-2014 (investigating now how that was possible; Informatica + Oracle 11.2, I believe).